# for each (root of variable) in SPSS

Tags: loops, spss

I'm new in SPSS program but I've tried to search a solution to my problem. The idea is find a way to loop through some variable names (or I think so). I want to create the variables `P216_XX`, `P217_XX`, `T211_XX` and `OCUPAC_XX`, with other variables like some inputs (`P216_13`, `P216_12`, `P216_11`, `P216_10`, `P217_13`, `P217_12`, `P217_11`, `P217_10`, `T211_13`, `T211_12`, `T211_11`, `T211_10`, `OCUPAC_13`, `OCUPAC_12`, `OCUPAC_11`, `OCUPAC_10` and `IIIDDDEEE`).

I'm following the next tedious instruction:

```
******TEDIOUS INSTRUCTION:

*****P216_XX.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=1)   P216_XX=P216_13.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=2)   P216_XX=P216_12.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=3)   P216_XX=P216_11.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=4)   P216_XX=P216_10.
EXECUTE.

*****P217_XX.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=1)   P217_XX=P217_13.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=2)   P217_XX=P217_12.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=3)   P217_XX=P217_11.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=4)   P217_XX=P217_10.
EXECUTE.

*****T211_XX.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=1)   T211_XX=T211_13.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=2)   T211_XX=T211_12.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=3)   T211_XX=T211_11.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=4)   T211_XX=T211_10.
EXECUTE.

*****OCUPAC_XX.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=1)   OCUPAC_XX=OCUPAC_13.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=2)   OCUPAC_XX=OCUPAC_12.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=3)   OCUPAC_XX=OCUPAC_11.
EXECUTE.
IF (IIIDDDEEE=4)   OCUPAC_XX=OCUPAC_10.
EXECUTE.
```

In stata, the form would reduce the previous syntax with something like that:

```
foreach x in  P216 P217 T211 OCUPAC {
replace `x'_XX=`x'_13 if IIIDDDEEE==1
replace `x'_XX=`x'_12 if IIIDDDEEE==2
replace `x'_XX=`x'_11 if IIIDDDEEE==3
replace `x'_XX=`x'_10 if IIIDDDEEE==4
}
*
```

In SPSS, I proved with vector, but SPSS don't accept me root in the vector, only variables. I don't know how to continue and I haven't found something similar yet

Is possible found a solution with native SPSS language? (I forgot to comment that in my work, the "administrator" doesn't allow us to install other programs like Python). What would be a possible solution?

Comment: By the way, you don't need all those "EXECUTES". They only add extra lines of code and slow down your work stream.

Comment: Okey, i'm going to modify my sintax with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There are a quite a lot of ways you can simplify this code, look up:

- [`DEFINE/ENDDEFINE`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_define.htm?lang=en), SPSS's macro language.
- [`DO IF`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_do_if.htm?lang=en)
- [`DO REPEAT`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_do_repeat_examples.htm?lang=en)

You need to be familiar with each and know what your end goal is to assess which option is best for you.

Comment: DO REPEAT will be close to the equivalent of the foreach Stata syntax.